# Que es mas efectivo? For o Foreach en PHP

Tags: php, loops

Hace tiempo vengo programando en php. Y tenia la siguiente duda en cuanto a la eficiencia de los recursos y la velocidad de como se comportan estos.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

**¿Que función es mas efectiva a la hora de recorrer un array?**

Estuve leyendo documentación donde indica que `foreach` esta hecho para recorrer array. Pero la pregunta es mas bien cual tiene mayor efectividad, ya sea por que accede a menos metodos o por que es mucho mas nativo.

Dejo un ejemplo para que se haga mas facil de entender:

**Ejemplo For:**

```
<?php 
     $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 
     $cantidad = count($colors);    

     for ($i = 0; $i <= $cantidad $i++) {
         echo $colors[$i]."<br>";
     }
?>
```

**Ejemplo Foreach:**

```
<?php 
     $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

     foreach ($colors as $value) {
         echo $value."<br>";
     }
?>
```

Agradezco el interés!

**NOTA:**

Tengo presente que a nivel de solo un par de datos, esto no se refleja. Pero la idea es presentarlo a nivel de muchos datos

**NOTA2:**

Como parte de una respuesta a que el proceso se hacia mas lento si en mi ciclo `for` colocase `count($colors)` he decidido separarlo para que se mida solo el for en si, y no el entre a métodos innecesarios.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3430538/4987172

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para recorrer un array en PHP, y hablamos de arrays un poco grandes, tipo 10 mil iteraciones, lo más eficiente será con foreach.

> Un for con un   **i < un numero** es el segundo más rápido. Finalmente lo
>   más lento es recorrer el array con un for  **i < count(array)**, porque
>   cada vez que incremente **i** llama a la función count del array.

Te dejo un ejemplo de ejecución.

```
$elements = array();

    ////
    // Array de  10,000 elementos con string aleatorio
    ////
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
            $elements[] = (string)rand(10000000, 99999999);
    }

    $time_start = microtime(true);

    ////
    // for 
    ////
    for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) { }

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $for_time = $time_end - $time_start;

    $time_start = microtime(true);

    ////
    // foreach 
    ////
    foreach($elements as $element) { }

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $foreach_time = $time_end - $time_start;

    echo "For tardo: " . number_format($for_time * 1000, 3) . "msn";
    echo "Foreach tardo: " . number_format($foreach_time * 1000, 3) . "msn";
```

> Salida: For tardo: 0.326msn
>
> Foreach tardo: 0.124msn

**NOTA:**

En caso de cambiar la siguiente linea

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($elements); $i++) { }
```

de esta forma:

```
$contar = count($elements);
for($i = 0; $i < $contar; $i++) { }
```

Se nota considerablemente el cambio. Y por tanto termina teniendo un mejor rendimiento ciclo `for`

Comment: Agradezco el punto. Ahora si esta es alojada anteriormente a una variable  y llamar a dicha variable el count? vale decir `$cantidad = count($colors)' y posteriormente en el ciclo `for` colocar `$cantidad`?

Comment: Si, vaya si no conoces el cuantos elementos tendrá el array,  puedes guardar el valor de count en una variable.

Comment: la pregunta, cambie el detalle que me mencionaste para dejarlo una variable. Y dado ahora este nuevo escenario. Que estaría mas certero?

Comment: Dejando previamente el count del array en variable, si mides los nuevos tiempos de ejecución, for mejora considerablemente al no estar llamando a función count

Answer (score 2):

Con este sencillo algoritmo podrías calcular el tiempo que se toma cada bucle en recorrer los mismos elementos.

Teniendo primero un `Array` con *10.000* valores aleatorios de `String`:

```
$elementos = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
    $elementos[] = (string)rand(10000000, 99999999);
}
```

Utilizaremos los dos bucles para hacer las pruebas de tiempo con el uso de las funciones `microtime`:

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Bucle for
for($i = 0; $i < count($elementos); $i++) { }

$time_end = microtime(true);
$for_time = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);

// Bucle foreach
foreach($elementos as $elemento) { }

$time_end = microtime(true);
$foreach_time = $time_end - $time_start;
```

Finalmente imprimimos los resultados:

```
echo "For tiempo: " . number_format($for_time * 1000, 3) . "ms\n";
echo "Foreach tiempo: " . number_format($foreach_time * 1000, 3) . "ms\n";
```

Dependiendo del ordenador que ejecute el programa obtendrás unos resultados u otros, pero visiblemente parece que el `foreach` es algo más rápido que el `for`.

***Mi resultado:***

> ```
> For tiempo: 0.003ms 
> Foreach tiempo: 0.001ms
> ```

[Aquí](https://gist.github.com/nodesocket/3909074/628478c74d736854f4499fa3383eb97e5db84b6f) tienes el código completo de la prueba

Answer (score 2):

Existe publicado un [benchmark](http://www.phpbench.com) sobre esto y la conclusión es la siguiente:

En todos los casos **el bucle `foreach` es sustancialmente más rápido** que los procedimientos `for` y `while ()`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Lo de dejar el subrayado de las palabras de usar el buscador de Chrome ha sido queriendo? :D

Answer (score 2):

Basado en sus propios códigos y haciendo variación para para incrementar el `array` y además hacer modificación ultima de colocar por separado `$contar = count($colors);`

Codigo:

```
<?php   
$elements = array();

////
// Array de  10,000 elementos con string aleatorio
////
for($i = 0; $i < 773139; $i++) {
        $elements[] = (string)rand(10000000, 99999999);
}

$time_start = microtime(true);

////
// for 
////
$contar = count($elements);
for($i = 0; $i < $contar; $i++) { }

$time_end = microtime(true);
$for_time = $time_end - $time_start;

$time_start = microtime(true);

////
// foreach 
////
foreach($elements as $element) { }

$time_end = microtime(true);
$foreach_time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "For tardo: " . number_format($for_time * 1000, 5) . "msn<br>";
echo "Foreach tardo: " . number_format($foreach_time * 1000, 5) . "msn";

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo los resultado puesto que no actualizaron respuestas anteriores. Y dejo los resultados en donde todas las veces ciclo `for` salio siempre mejor. Agradezco a @Voiser por ser pro-activo con este tema

Comment: Esta respuesta carece de sentido, si ya has marcado una respuesta como correcta.

Comment: @cnbandicoot claro que tiene sentido, e indique el por que. Puesto que antes tenia `for($i = 0; $i < count($elementos); $i++) { }` y ahora es `$contar = count($elementos); for($i = 0; $i < $contar; $i++) { }` hace una gran diferencia. Ninguno de los que indico la respuesta anterior, actualizo al caso y por eso coloque el ejemplo dado que me dieron las herramientas para determinar, pero para que los nuevos usuarios no quedaran con una mala idea del caso anterior con el nuevo caso. Puesto que se pensaba que `foreach` indicaron como mejor, y actualizando el escenario `for` resulta mejor. Fijate!

Answer (score 0):

```
"el for tardó"  "el foreach tardó"
109.44486msn    146.44790msn
119.28487msn    160.94422msn
142.61222msn    143.96286msn
 99.05100msn    122.46180msn
157.92990msn    144.73200msn
147.69983msn    168.13302msn
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la conclusión que obtienes? ¿Cuál es la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Estuve leyendo las respuestas y, en particular, en la que propusieron ejecutar un count(array) antes de ejecutar el cliclo for, obteniendo como resultado que el ciclo for era más rápido que el foreach, pero pude notar que hay un error en la comparación que se está haciendo, que explico a continuación. Al hacer:

```
foreach($array as $element) { }
```

Este método si está recorriendo el array en cuestión, sin embargo, al hacer:

```
$contar = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $contar; $i++) { }
```

Lo que se está haciendo es simplemente ejecutar un ciclo 'for' n-veces, desde 0 hasta la longitud del array, pero no se recorre el array mismo, lo que, según creo, resulta ser una comparación inválida de ambos métodos.

Con base en los ejemplos antes dados, hice una pequeña adaptación en que cada valor del array recorrido, es asignado a otro. El resultado es que se obtienen tiempos ligeramente menores usando 'foreach', la mayoría de las veces, pero no siempre. Les dejo el código que usé por si lo quieren probar ustedes mismos. Yo lo hice en la página: http://phptester.net/

```
<?php
$elements = array();

////
// Array de  10,000 elementos con string aleatorio
////
for($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        $elements[] = (string)rand(10000, 99999);
}


$a = [];
$time_start = microtime(true);

////
// for 
////
$contar = count($elements);
for($i = 0; $i < $contar; $i++) { 
$a[$i] = $elements[$i];
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
$for_time = $time_end - $time_start;

$b=[];
$time_start = microtime(true);

////
// foreach 
////
foreach($elements as $i => $element) { 
$b[$i] = $element;
}

$time_end = microtime(true);
$foreach_time = $time_end - $time_start;


echo "For tardó: " . number_format($for_time * 1000, 5) . "msn<br>";
echo "Foreach tardó: " . number_format($foreach_time * 1000, 5) . "msn";
```